# How to escape char in Python 3 ''' string?

Tags: string, escaping, python-3.x, string-formatting

Here is the String:

```
'''This is a test { <-- escape these ---> } '''
```

I would like to escape the

> {

and

> }

in format method, how can I do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: {{ and }}.

Try this:

```
'''This is a test {{ <-- escape these ---> }} and the value is {0}'''.format(42)
```